# Hibernate and JSF - multiplied rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I'm working on my first project using **JSF2 + Hibernate 4.3**. I think I have a problem with `@ManyToMany` relation.

Relevant tables:

```
 - EMPLOYEE (id, first_name, last_name,...)
 - TASK (id, title, description,...)
 - EMPLOYEE_TASK (id, employee_id, task_id)
```

Contents of `EMPLOYEE_TASK` table:

```
ID  |   EMPLOYEE_ID |   TASK_ID
--------------------------------
1   |       9       |   1
2   |       9       |   2
3   |       9       |   3
4   |       7       |   1
5   |       8       |   2
6   |       6       |   1
```

Relevant code parts:

**Employee.java**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "workers")
private List<Task> myWorkingTasks;
```

**Task.java**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_task", catalog = "employeemanager", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",
                        nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    private List<Employee> workers;
```

**TaskOverview.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TaskOverview {
    private int taskId;
    private Task task;

    public void init() {
        if (taskId > 0) {
            task = TaskDAO.findById(taskId);
        }
    }

    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

**taskView.xhtml**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{taskOverview.task.workers}" var="worker">
    <h:outputText value="#{worker.firstName} #{worker.lastName}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

So, when I open the page **taskView.xhtml?taskId=3**, I should see only Employee #3 in the workers list. But for some reason, his name is printed twice. If I open the same page for **taskId=2**, the two employees will be printed four times. Same for **taskId=1**, the three employees are printed four times.

Other stuff in my application (@OneToMany, @ManyToOne and @OneToOne) works fine.

I appreciate any help you guys can provide :)

**Edit (and the solution):**
The problem was definitely in the Hibernate part (actually, the programmer was the problem :)). I tried to rewrite everything from the scratch and now it works as intended.

Comment: Why would this be a JSF problem? Are you implying that it works fine when you use e.g. `System.out.println()` to present the list contents instead of a JSF page?

Comment: @BalusC I haven't tried that, but since I was using JSF in this case, I supposed that I should put that tag too.

Comment: To increase chance in getting an answer, you should try to make the question as focused as possible instead of too broad. Otherwise your question is more likely to be ignored by Hibernate users who don't happen to know something about JSF. Isolate your problem as much as possible. For example: "My TaskDAO.findById(taskId) returns a task object which contains duplicate workers". In such case it's completely irrelevant to add boilerplate code which merely presents the model, such as JSF. You should go for the most simplest way: `System.out.println()`.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. I've tried to load all `Employee`s and to get all of their `Task`s and to print them. Everything is working fine, each list is correct. So I believe that Hibernate works fine. It might be a JSF problem... I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In that case, you should remove all Hibernate related noise and start off with a hardcoded list of minimal objects (e.g. maps/strings). Otherwise your question is more likely to be ignored by JSF users who don't happen to know something about Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was definitely in the Hibernate part (actually, the programmer was the problem :)). I tried to rewrite everything from the scratch and now it works as intended.